# _AsteroidsReact 360 Module2.default.printOut is not a function (Unable to call module method from client.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-360

For my react 360 project, I have the following code in my `client.js` file:

```
import { ReactInstance } from 'react-360-web';
import AsteroidsModule from './AsteroidsModule';
import * as THREE from 'three';

function init(bundle, parent, options = {}) {
  const scene = new THREE.Scene();
  const r360 = new ReactInstance(bundle, parent, {
    // Add custom options here
    fullScreen: true,
    nativeModules: [
      new AsteroidsModule(scene),
    ],

                  Problem
    ***************************************
    frame: () => {
      AsteroidsModule.printOut('hello');
    },
    ***************************************

    ...options,
  });

  ........code...
```

Next, I have the following code in a seperate `AsteroidsModule` file. The code is from a presentation on reactvr and has the following contents:

```
import { Module } from 'react-360-web';
import * as THREE from 'three';

export default class AsteroidsModule extends Module {
  constructor(scene) {
    // The name of the module in NativeModules
    super('AsteroidsModule');

    this.scene = scene;
    this.time = 0;
    this.meshes = [];
  }

  printOut(string) {
    console.log(string);
  }

  populate() {
   ....code....
  }

  render() {
   ....code......
  }
}
```

React 360 on initialization has a `frame:` option that allows me to perform code on every frame render. The code that I want to perform in this case for testing purposes is the `AsteroidsModule.printOut('hello')` method call. In the console this leads to the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: _AsteroidsModule2.default.printOut is not a function
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this error. I have imported the needed module on top of the file. I've tried to pick at this apart piece by piece but I don't know why it's not rendering. Could someone assist me with what could be the possible problem?

Comment: `AsteroidsModule.printOut` is an instance method. You need to initialize `AsteroidsModule` by calling (`new AsteroidsModule(...)`), and then call `.printOut` on *that* object.

Comment: You can also look to convert `.printOut` to a static method as shown [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static).